# Call other instance methods from java-me inner class

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

```
public class Outer 
{
     Grid g=new Grid();
     public class Inner
     {
         // how do I call a grid class function from this inner class?
     }
}

public class Grid
{
     Grid(){}
     void up(){}
}
```

Comment: It seems like this is a Java question. What does it have to do with BlackBerry? **Also**, the question is unclear--what do you mean by "call grid class function thro inner class"? Are you aware that `g` is visible to all functions in class `inner`?

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Outer 
{
     Grid g=new Grid();

     public class Inner
     {
         public void callG()
         {
             g.up();
         }
     }
}
```